# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryOptions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-bigquery

I'm starting to work with GCP, and I wanted to make a test just to see how to get data from a dataset in BigQuery through Eclipse. I used an existing post in which this was very well explained, but when following the steps and after creating my maven project, I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryOptions
    at com.test_Emergya01.getData_FromBQ.getData.main(getData.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Dataset;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.DatasetInfo;


public class getData 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        // Instantiates a client
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
                .setProjectId("mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008").build().getService();

        String datasetName = "GA_data";

        Dataset dataset = bigquery.getDataset(datasetName);

        System.out.printf("Dataset %s fetched.%n", dataset.getDatasetId().getDataset());
    }
}
```

And this is the content of my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test-01</groupId>
  <artifactId>getData_FromBQ</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>getData_FromBQ</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test_01.getData_FromBQ.getData</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the application? This is simply a class path issue.

Comment: Thank you @Abhijit. I'm running the packaged .jar file inside the 'target' folder: java -jar jarFile.jar

Comment: see my answer below. It will work for your. Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam I don't see your answer.

Comment: @enlelin, I have deleted and now undelete is again if that is helpful for you. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam Thanks! I'm try to reproduce and to understand this since it seems to be class issue, as you mentioned.

Comment: @David Could you provide the post that you have followed to get Bigquery data through Eclipse?

Comment: @David can you please share the pom.xml file, I am also getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with class path. As you are using maven build your project folder is the root directory/folder for a maven project. Hence you have to run your jar file from your project folder like below. Also make sure all the jar files/packages are in your class path.

```
 java -jar target/yourproject.jar
```

Also create one class path variable like below and refer it in your command line:-

```
 CP="C:\lib\example.jar;C:\another\location\example2.jar..."

 java -cp %CP% -jar target/yourproject.jar
```

For Unix environment:-

```
CP="/../lib/example.jar:/../another/location/example2.jar..."

 java -cp "$CP" -jar target/yourproject.jar
```

Comment: Thanks again @Abhijit. That's the way I'm running the project, but it doesn't work. Maybe it's something related to the dependencies in the POM file.

Comment: Just make sure all the jar files/packages are in your class path.